# Can I enter the US border (El paso) with an F-1 visa after my study program has ended?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, study

I have an F-1 visa, and I want to go to El Paso, TX with my family that lives there. Is it possible to cross the border with my visa? It doesn't  expire until 2020.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter when your visa expires.  If your program has ended, you cannot enter the US in F-1 status.  The immigration officer at the border will check your I-20 to ensure that you are eligible for F-1 status; if your program has ended, you won't have a valid I-20.

To enter the US, therefore, you'll need a B visa unless you're eligible for the visa waiver program or other visa-free entry.